# Is there a function similar to Excel's "Evaluate Formula" to help debug complex Google Sheets formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Excel there is a button to "Evaluate Formula", so I could step through whatever formula I wrote and find where I messed up. Is there anything equivalent in Google Sheets?

EDIT:
I am not referring to a function called "evaluate".
[image]
There is a button in excel (see picture) that lets you step through the function in a cell that you have selected, and is very useful to see why it is returning something that you didn't expect (error, etc.).

I don't think this is a duplicate question. I searched StackExchange, and did not see a question similar to what I asked.
This is not a VBA or AppScript question, this is purely for formulas inputted into cells.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell

Comment: its not the same. Excel has an "Evaluate Function" button that lets you step through the logic of the formula in whatever cell you have selected. It is really useful when the cell doesn't give you the output you expected

Comment: I see. It doesn't have that feature either.

Answer (score 1):

As of February 13, 2024, Google Sheets doesn't have a **built-in** feature similar to

> a button to "Evaluate Formula", so I could step through whatever formula I wrote and find where I messed up

Google Sheets can be extended (add more features) by installing add-ons and using Google Apps Script.

**Google Sheets Add-ons**
To learn about the available add-ons, lick the **Extensions** menu on the Google Sheets editor, then click on **Get add-ons**.

[image: Extended "Extensions" menu, showing the "Get add-ons" option]

Tip: Click the **Help** > **Search the menus** then type `add-ons`

Another option is to go directly to the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace)

[image: Extended "Works with" filter, showing the "Sheets" option]

For example, an add-on called [Formula Tracer](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/formula_tracer/502871872643). At first glance, it looks to me that it might add the feature you are looking for. I haven't used it. Please read the add-on listing carefully.

Before installing any add-on, as it should be done before using any third-party software, if available, look at the aggregated ratings (stars) and the reviews and ensure that you understand the **Privacy Policy** and the **Terms of Service**.

Tip: [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) is another Stack Exchange network site focusing on software recommendations. Asking for a Google Sheets add-on recommendation might be on-topic. Before posting a question or answer, please check out their **[tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)**.

**Google Apps Script**

On the **Extensions** menu I mentioned above, there is also the option to create/open a bounded Google Apps Script project: **App Script**. This option will open the **Google Apps Script editor** (IDE), showing the top project file. The more you know about programming and JavaScript, the better chances you can get the most out of this web app. If you learn about web development, you should be able to craft custom functions and simple web apps that help you to "evaluate" your formulas very quickly.

## Related

- [Is there a way to evaluate a formula stored in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16303680/1595451)
  This question and answer was created several years ago on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Over the years, it had gotten answers.